# Regex, how can I ignore partial matches? For instance ".co" would match ".com" when I regex for words between two spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to regex & extract some URLs from a large text file. Most URLs don't have an HTTP/HTTPS affixed to them so it is making this a lot more difficult.

If I want to regex for URLs containing ".co", I made it so the regex finds ".co" and selects from the first space before the occurrence and to first space after the occurence using:

```
(\S+\.co\S+)
```

But the problem with this comes when I have URLs with the .com TLD in the file too.

For example, this regex selects all URLs from below instead of only the ".co" URLs

```
pizza.com/test is good 
pizza.co/test is great
```

Regex Extracts:

```
pizza.com/test
pizza.co/test
```

I only want it to extract:

```
pizza.co/test
```

Here is my regexr example: https://regexr.com/5hl2h

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this with regex? Or should I look for an alternative solution?

Much appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
\S+\.co(?!m)\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\.co(?!m)` Match `.co` not directly followed by m
- `\S*` Match 0+ non whitespace chars to also match ending with `.co`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cfMqBF/1)

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, and I figured out a solution that works with all tlds. Instead of m I can use [a-z]. Much appreciate it! 

```\S+\.net(?![a-z])\S*```